# how to play video(mp4,3gp,etc) and mp3 on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, video

how to play video or .mp3 on .jsp

my code is

```
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" EnableContextMenu="false" autostart="false" width="320" height="240" loop="false" src="E:/ifwOnline/web/Images/PostVideos/0012 Vandushajanand.mp3" />
....
.
.
.    .
.
.
.
```

but it not work...
and also not show any player to play video.... how to solve it....
...............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't specify your file path as src="E:/ifwOnline/web/Images/PostVideos/0012 Vandushajanand.mp3". you have to deploy it in your web server and give the path as an URL like :

```html
localhost:<port>/<applicationName>/video/0012 Vandushajanand.mp3
```

and keep in mind, if you are working on unix environment, you must remove spaces from your file name. you can use '_' instead of spaces. otherwise it will work only on windows environments.

Hope this helps you !

Comment: no it not working....my code is .....................           <video  id = "example_video_1" class  
                                                                
                                                            ="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
 

  <source src="http://localhost:8084<%= request.getContextPath()%>/web/Images/PostVideos/1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                                                            </video>

Comment: OK I GET PROBLAM ...THE PROBLEM IS IN PATH .....SOLUTION IS ...PATH====  src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Images/PostVideos/1.MP4"............OK THANKS .....IT WORK FINE....

Comment: great it helps...the issue was with your path and it should be a link for src attribute. so why don't you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on how to do that:

http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/learnwebdesign_chap22/

It is an extract from an O' Reilly book called "Learning Web Design".